# What are the abstract "patterns" on the edges of the paper of Jewish seforim?

Tags: minhag, jewish-books

I've always wondered but never thought to ask: what are these abstract paper patterns on some Jewish seforim? As the two books in bottom center of example photo: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jbhcKUqaVsA/VpVGyNLtKJI/AAAAAAAADmY/OP3pRyfWq2g/s1600/19.jpg

It sort of looks like camoflouge, but in red hues. Yes I know it's almost Purim, but don't giggle. I'm seriously wondering this.

You will find this most often on the really "serious" seforim that are all-Hebrew, come from the ultra orthodox people in Israel. Kaftor siddurim have them for example.

Do they mean anything? (Like, is this sort of analogous to the "barcode" of the pre-WWII tallits?) Or is this just a way to make the books appear mehudar (beautified, superior)? To me, it's always just seemed kind of...odd. I don't understand what it has ever done to beautify or enhance or elevate the sefer it is found on.

Kol Tuv

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/479140847830956575/

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yiddidiah and thanks for this first question. Love the barcode idea. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!